# How to make a gradient overlay at bottom of list to indicate more items

Tags: css

I'm trying to make (using only CSS3) an edge that can be either on the bottom, left, top, or right edge of a container div, so that the list of elements inside it get overlapped by it, as a visual indicator to the user that there are more items. See mockup below. How can I do this in CSS3? (black box is set to `overflow: scroll`)

Using `box-shadow` with `inset` doesn't work because that's background and the shadows need to overlay the content yet the content still needs to be clickable and scrollable.

[image: mockup]

Answer (score 6):

A pseudo element could be used too : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sghyb

HTML test

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>List</li>
     ...
  </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS test

```
nav {
  display:table;
  margin:auto;
  font-size:50px;
  position:relative;
}
nav:after {
  content:' ';
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:17px;
  height:1em;
  top:6.3em;
  background:linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    rgba(0,0,0,0),
    rgba(0,0,0,0.95) 50%
  );
  z-index:1;
}
ul {
  background:#000;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  color:silver;
  width:15em;
  height:7.3em;
  overflow:auto;
}
li {
  display:block;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do it like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="scroll">

        <div class="content">
        ## content to scroll
        </div>
        <div class="shade"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.scroll { position:relative;}
.shade  { position:absolute; bottom:0; height:30px; z-index:10;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(152,152,152,0) 40%, rgba(23,23,23,1) 90%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 99%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(40%,rgba(152,152,152,0)), color-stop(90%,rgba(23,23,23,1)), color-stop(99%,rgba(0,0,0,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(152,152,152,0) 40%,rgba(23,23,23,1) 90%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 99%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(152,152,152,0) 40%,rgba(23,23,23,1) 90%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 99%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(152,152,152,0) 40%,rgba(23,23,23,1) 90%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 99%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(152,152,152,0) 40%,rgba(23,23,23,1) 90%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 99%); /* W3C */
}
```

Of course style all elements as needed, and if your '.scroll' is element is a '' just
have your '.shade' an LI.

Answer (score -1):

Add a layer (div) with `position:absolute` to the bottom (`bottom:0px; left:0px; right:0px;`) of the container div with `z-index` and needed gradient.