# Gradient element that indicates scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to make a gradient at the bottom of my element that indicates you can scroll further.
I've tried various methods but end op only being able to make the gradient at the bottom of my whole wrapper. I want the gradient to remain at the same spot and not move as you scroll.

Example of somewhat what I want, but a bit cleaner(see bottom of calendar): [image: Gradient example] :

Full page JSFiddle, commented with element that aren't relevant: https://jsfiddle.net/uyqeov90/

HTML:

```
<div class="kwrapper">
        <div class="kalender sammen">
            <h2>Det sker på Åpark kollegiet</h2>
            <p>Her kan du se de events der afholdes på Åpark kollegiet og forskellige spændende arrangementer rundt om i
                Århus by.
                <br>
                Ønsker du at tilføje et event til kalenderen så skal du sende en mail med følgende info:
                <ul>
                    <li>Dato</li>
                    <li>Klokkeslæt</li>
                    <li>Adresse</li>
                    <li>Pris (hvis arrangementet koster penge)</li>
                    <li>og evt deltager-max</li>
                </ul>
                <form class="#" method="get" action="#">
                    <button type="submit" class="default-button"><i class="far fa-envelope"></i>  Send en mail til bestyrelsen</button>
                </form>
            </p>

        </div>
        <div class="kalender stor">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://stylemygcal.com/widget.js"></script>
            <div class="smgc-calendar-placeholder" id="smgc-cal-l55Pd4QGM6FAQSno1l8g"></div>
        </div>
    </div>`
```

CSS:

```
.kwrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 500px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

  .kwrapper:before {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, white);
  }

.kwrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.kwrapper::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical {
    width: 20px;
}

.kwrapper::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal {
    height: 20px;
}

.kwrapper::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.kalender {
    padding: 20px;
}

.tekst,
.sammen {
    width: 25%;
    margin-left: 30px;
    line-height: 22px;
}

.stor {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    width: 60%;
}

@media (max-width: 990px) {

    .kwrapper {
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
    }

    .tekst,
    .sammen {
        margin-left: 15px;
        margin-right: 15px;
    }

    .kalender {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .kalender stor {
        order: 3;
    }

    .kalender tekst {
        order: 1;
    }

    .kalender sammen {
        order: 2;
    }
}

.kwrapper h2, .container h3 {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

.kwrapper img,
.kwrapper a {
    visibility: hidden !important;
    opacity: 0 !important;
    display: none !important;
}

.default-button {
    background-color: #91d184;
    border-radius: 100px;
    border-style: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.default-button:hover {
    background-color: #74A769;
}

.sammen form {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

edit: fixed [image]

Comment: I can't see any element with a gradient effect on your JSFiddle. Also, JSFiddle parser is flagging up some mistakes on your CSS rules.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/text-fade-read-more/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a gradient overlay at bottom of list to indicate more items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24227636/how-to-make-a-gradient-overlay-at-bottom-of-list-to-indicate-more-items)

Comment: @melancia here they actually seem to be in a more complex situation, where the scrolling element doesn't have a fixed width, and doesn't take the full width of its parent. But they could simplify a lot the code so it's easier for us to help them.

Comment: @melancia The trick was to put my wrapper inside another <div> element and then have that element hold the gradient. I've edited my main post if you want to see how it turned out, works responsively as well. Thank you for your help!